# Using Scala to Override a Java method that uses "? extends"

Tags: scala

So I have a Java method:

```
public abstract List<Class<? extends MyClass>> getListOfClasses();
```

and I need to override it in Scala. Here is how I am currently doing it:

```
override def getListOfClasses: java.util.List[Class[_ <: MyClass[_]]] = { null }
```

However, this does not compile, and I get the error: method getListOfClasses has incompatible type

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
MyClass is defined in Java like this:

```
abstract class MyClass[T] extends MyOtherClass[T] {...}
```

FINAL EDIT:
As suggested by @AlexeyRomanov below, changing my Java method return type fixed the problem:

```
public abstract List<Class<? extends MyClass<?>>> getListOfClasses();
```

Comment: Shot in the dark, but do you need to add a pair of parens `()`  to the end of the Scala `def`?

Comment: For me it is compiling or am I doing something wrong. Take a look on this project: https://github.com/paweln1986/SOFIssue

Comment: The Java signature is already problematic, since it uses a raw type. Can you try changing it to `List<Class<? extends MyClass<?>>>` (and Scala signature as in the question)?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Thank you, your suggestion worked!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it for more on raw types.

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly but `asInstanceOf` works.
This ugliness comes from Java's inability to express covariance and contra-variance.

---

Interface:

```
import java.util.List;
public abstract class Game2J {
  public interface MyClass {}

  public abstract List<Class<? extends MyClass>> getListOfClasses();
}
```

Scala code:

```
import java.util

import Game2J.MyClass
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

class Game2S extends Game2J {
  class MyClass1 extends MyClass
  class MyClass2 extends MyClass

  override def getListOfClasses: util.List[Class[_ <: MyClass]] =
    List(classOf[MyClass1], classOf[MyClass2]).asJava.asInstanceOf[util.List[Class[_ <: MyClass]]]
}
```

Working example:

```
public class Game2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Game2S().getListOfClasses().stream().forEach((cl) -> System.out.println(cl.getSimpleName()));
  }
}
```